# Send a notification from AppDelegate to ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

need your help. I implement these Delegate Method to the AppDelegate.m:

```
    -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
           openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation {
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
        //Valid URL, send a message to the view controller with the url
    }
    else {
        //No valid url
    }
    return YES;
```

But now, I need the URL not in the AppDelegate but in my ViewController. How I can "send" them the url or how I can implement these Delegate Method to the ViewController?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use `NSNotificationCenter` as shown below:

Firstly post Notification in your app delegate as  :

```
NSDictionary *_dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newIndex],nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:SELECTED_INDEX,nil]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SELECT_INDEX_NOTIFICATION object:nil userInfo:_dictionary];
```

then register the ViewController you want to observe this notification as

```
/***** To register and unregister for notification on recieving messages *****/
- (void)registerForNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(yourCustomMethod:)
                                                 name:SELECT_INDEX_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
}

/*** Your custom method called on notification ***/
-(void)yourCustomMethod:(NSNotification*)_notification
{
    [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSString *selectedIndex=[[_notification userInfo] objectForKey:SELECTED_INDEX];
    NSLog(@"selectedIndex  : %@",selectedIndex);

}
```

call this method in ViewDidLoad as :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [self registerForNotifications];
}
```

and then on UnLoad remove this observer by calling this method :

```
-(void)unregisterForNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:SELECT_INDEX_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
}


-(void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self unregisterForNotifications];
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 6):

You can post a local notification like this, where notification name will be used by the receiver to subscribe.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:@"Data" 
    object:nil];
```

And in your viewController subscribe the notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(getData:) 
    notificationName:@"Data" 
    object:nil];

- getData:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSString *tappedIndex = [[_notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"KEY"];
}
```

For More About the [NSNotificationCenter Can go with this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Hi, where i have to put this code: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(getData:) 
    notificationName:@"Data" 
    object:yourdata];

Comment: where you want to check the notification data like you can call it into viewDidLoad

Comment: How can we get yourData as a object in viewController ?

Comment: just put nil for the object reference on the ViewController, the data is attached to the actual notification.