# Change UILabel in View Controller from Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbcentralmanager

I am very new to iOS development and I'm struggling to make an app which connects to BLE devices. As I have many view controllers I need to keep the peripheral always connected in all of them.

To achieve this, I implemented all the BLE connection methods in a `Singleton`. This works just great, I call the connect method from `View Controller` and the `Singleton` connects to the peripheral.

Now, the problem is I have a `UILabel` in my view controller which I would like to update with the connection state (scanning, connecting, connected, disconnected) from the `Singleton`.

So I tried to get instance from the `View Controller` and change the label directly like:

```
MainViewController *controller = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
controller.myLabel.text =  @"TEST";
```

I also instantiated the view controller class like:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle: nil];
MainViewController *controller = (MainViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];
```

Then I tried to create a method in the main `View Controller`:

```
- (void) updateLabel:(NSString *) labelText{
     NSLog(@"CALLED IN MAIN");
     self.myLabel.text = labelText;
 }
```

And call it from `Singleton` like:

```
MainViewController *controller = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[controller updateLabel:@"TEST"]
```

Which was called properly (`NSLog` was shown) but the label was not updated.

I don't really know how to update my `View Controller` label from the `Singleton`. Don't know neither if the way I'm trying to do it is the right one or not.

Any advice or help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

----- **UPDATE:** -----

Thanks to Mundi and Nikita, I got a better way to implement what I need through NSNotification. For all those who need it here is how I do it:

In my `View Controller` in `viewDidLoad` I call:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateConnectionLabel:) name:@"connectionLabelNotification" object:nil];
```

Then in the same class I implement the notification observer method like:

```
- (void)updateConnectionLabel:(NSNotification *) notification {
     if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"connectionLabelNotification"]) {
        self.connectionLabel.text = notification.object; //The object is a NSString
     }
}
```

Then in my `Singleton`, when I need I call:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"connectionLabelNotification" object:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CONNECTED"]];
```

When the `View Controller` receives the notification from the `Singleton` it updates the label with the text I add on the notification object (in this case @"CONNECTED").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is via `NSNotification`. This communication device is meant for exactly this kind of situation. It broadcast a message without caring whether the potential receiver is available.

In your view controllers, you call `NSNotificationCenter`'s `addObserver` / `removeObserver` when they appear / disappear. You post the notification via `postNotification:`.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the `NSNotification` docs. Do you recommend any example/tutorial?

Comment: Some more explanations  added to answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found a good example and now I got what I need. LINK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498422/update-text-label-from-another-view

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `NSNotification`.

Here is sample code:

in **viewDidLoad**:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(mySelector:)
                                             name:DeviceStateChanged
                                           object:nil];
```

in **dealloc**:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:DeviceStateChanged
                                              object:nil];
```

also add a method in **ViewController**:

```
- (void) mySelector:(NSNotification *) notification {
    // action performed
}
```

in **Sigleton**

```
- (void) foo {
    /// some actions

    // device connected
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:DeviceStateChanged object:self];

    ///
}
```

Recommendation: move notification name to your constants and use constant name. For naming convention look at Apple guidelines

Comment: Thanks a lot! Already found the answer thanks to Mundi, but your example may also work. I upvoted your answer!