# Accessing ViewController from custom delegate

Tags: ios, swift3

Let me start by saying that I am not a Swift/iOS developer.

I have created a custom `UIApplication` in order to catch all the touch event. I want to perform some actions when the screen is left untouched for a while.

Below is my code so far:

```
import UIKit

@objc(MyApplication)

class MyApplication: UIApplication {

    var screenUnTouchedTimer:Timer?

    override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {
        screenUnTouchedTimer?.invalidate()

        screenUnTouchedTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.makeScreenDim), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);

        // Ignore .Motion and .RemoteControl event simply everything else then .Touches
        if event.type != .touches {
            super.sendEvent(event)
            return
        }

        // .Touches only
        var restartTimer = true
        if let touches = event.allTouches {
            // At least one touch in progress? Do not restart timer, just invalidate it
            self.makeScreenBright()
            for touch in touches.enumerated() {
                if touch.element.phase != .cancelled && touch.element.phase != .ended {
                    restartTimer = false
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if restartTimer {
            // Touches ended || cancelled, restart timer
            //print("Touches ended. Restart timer")
        } else {
            // Touches in progress - !ended, !cancelled, just invalidate it
            //print("Touches in progress. Invalidate timer")
            //screenUnTouchedTimer?.invalidate() // can be done as soon as this class is called, like above instead
        }

        super.sendEvent(event)
    }

    func makeScreenDim() {
        UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.15)
        //print("makeScreenDim")
    }

    func makeScreenBright() {
        UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.5)
        //print("makeScreenBright")
    }

}
```

The above code works just fine, the screen is dimmed after 10 seconds as expected.
But I also would like to change some of the user interface stuff shown on my ViewController but I don't know how to access the viewController from `MyApplication`-class.

I tried the following which I think should be the way to do it:

```
var vc = ViewController()
vc.clearUserInterface()
```

How should I go about to call a function in the ViewController?

Comment: is it the currently visible viewController you would like to have access to?

Comment: @dirtydanee yes, I only have one ViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if u have one viewController, you can access the `keyWindow`'s `rootViewController` property.

```
  if let vc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? YourViewController {
       // do what u would like to
  }
```

Comment: perfect and quick :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to get current visible screen from app delegate, below is code.

```
func getVisibleViewController(_ rootViewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {

var rootVC = rootViewController
if rootVC == nil {
    rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
}

if rootVC?.presentedViewController == nil {
    return rootVC
}

if let presented = rootVC?.presentedViewController {
    if presented.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self) {
        let navigationController = presented as! UINavigationController
        return navigationController.viewControllers.last!
    }

    if presented.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self) {
        let tabBarController = presented as! UITabBarController
        return tabBarController.selectedViewController!
    }

    return getVisibleViewController(presented)
}
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this solution by using NotificationCenter https://stackoverflow.com/a/16458307/7205821 , but this code is written in Obj C, so if you have problem with that I can write you Swift implementation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your answer does not carry too much value for the raised question, and it does not solve the reported bug/problem. For the future, here is some information, how to crack a awesome answer on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer